# Linux-to-Windows: Hard drive not recognized

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

**Backstory:** When I started my new job, I inherited a computer running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell T7600 and who-knows-what-else.  I don't have a background or interest in computer science and Linux just isn't working for me, so I'm trying to install Windows 10 instead.  I'd prefer not to use a virtual machine or dual-boot, I'd rather start with a clean Windows machine.

When I boot from my Windows 10 ISO, I'm able to begin the installation process.  I choose 'Custom install' instead of 'Upgrade.'  Then I get an error: "We couldn't find any drives.  To get a storage driver, click Load driver."

**Here's some information about my drive:**

In BIOS/System Configuration/Drives, I see 2 DVD-related drives as well as HDD-0, which is a Toshiba DT01ACA300 (I think this is my main hard drive?).

When I boot in Ubuntu and call `lsblk`, I see:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT              LABEL
sda             2.7T                         
├─sda1 vfat     500M                         ESP
├─sda2 vfat      40M                         DIAGS
├─sda3          128M                         
├─sda4 ntfs     750M                         RECOVERY
├─sda5 ntfs   931.3G                         OS
├─sda6 swap    30.5G [SWAP]                  
├─sda7 ext4     1.8T /                       
└─sda8            4M                         
sr0            1024M                         
sr1             3.7G /media/sisir/UDF Volume   (DVD I believe)
```

**What I think I understand:** The Toshiba drive is 3TB, and Windows doesn't support some drives over 2TB. I'm guessing this is the problem.

**What I don't understand:** Do I need to partition the drive to solve the problem? Is the drive already partitioned? Can I convert my drive to GPT? Will I need a new drive?

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm doing my best but this is a steep learning curve.

Comment: "Windows doesn't support some drives over 2Tb. I'm guessing this is the problem." - This is false.  Your drive is already GPT based on the fact its 2.7TB, not 2TB, and the number of partitions that exist on it.

Answer (score 0):

> We couldn't find any drives. To get a storage driver, click Load driver.

In order to find your disk windows needs to find and recognise the controller your disk is connected to. You need a driver for this.

Most of the time this no longer is an issue since windows ships with lots of build in drivers, but your system is a [Dell precision workstation](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_Precision_T7600_Spec_Sheet.pdf) which ships with a [Dell PERC H310](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/dell-perc-h310-spec-sheet.pdf) RAID card.

Some googling indicates that this older Hardware RAID card has no windows 10 drivers.

That leave you with two options:

1. Use the windows server drivers and hope it is stable.
2. Or change the connection to the HDD, moving it from the RAID card to one of the SATA ports on the motherboard.

---

I think that solves the problem, but for completeness sake:

> The Toshiba drive is 3TB, and Windows doesn't support some drives over 2TB.

Windows works just fine with drives exceeding 2 TiB. The problem lies in older (512 byte sector) drives and MBR.  MBR is an old old old ancient format which is showing its age. It has since been replaced by GPT.

> Do I need to partition the drive to solve the problem?

No.

> Is the drive already partitioned?

Yes, your post even lists the partitions on it.

> Can I convert my drive to GPT?

The drive is already partitioned using the GPT scheme.

> Will I need a new drive?

Nope. The drive is working perfectly fine. And it will play fine with windows once windows finds the drive. Which it will once you either tell it how to talk to the drive (aka install the drivers) or if you move it to one of the SATA-III or SATA-II ports on the motherboard. (The specs list quite a few of those).

Comment: Drive is already GPT, so conversion required, but I agree with everything else.

Comment: Drat. Missed SDA1 as EFI system partition. Good catch.

Comment: NP; So I would agree the reason Windows cannot see the drive, is because the lack of a RAID driver, and for no other reason.